# Matlab: Labeling Data Points in a Polar Plot

Tags: matlab, label, polar-coordinates

I have an interesting question to ask, I have searched thoroughly and to my dismay it seems that no has had trouble with this. I would like to label all the data points in a polar plot in Matlab. The code is very simple so far, it is as follows:

```
close all
clear all

% Load all the datasets
%load('matlab.mat')

% These lines serve the same purpose as the load('matlab.mat')
PSA=[5.45938528888889;3.13809934444444;5.42622406111111;2.48185610000000];
NSA=[5.32150439444444;0.767944222222222;5.32499505000000;0.420623994444444];
PST=[1.69085714290000;2.68685714290000;0.688857142900000;0.688857142900000];
NST=[2.32914285710000;1.30914285710000;1.30914285710000;0.709142857100000];

% Global Constants
PI=3.14159;

% Converts the data points (in degrees originally) into radians
PSA=PSA.*(PI/180);
NSA=NSA.*(PI/180);

% Scaling, assumed that within the polar plot function that the maximum
% value is 1.0, so I scaled the data set to be fractions of 1 as opposed to
% values of 3
PST_1=PST./3;

figure(1)
polar(PSA,PST,'.');
h=text(PST(1,1), 2, ' \leftarrow foo');
% text(PositiveStationAzimuth(2,1), PositiveStationTime(2,1), ... PositiveStationName(2,1));
% text(PositiveStationAzimuth(3,1), PositiveStationTime(3,1), ... PositiveStationName(3,1));
% text(PositiveStationAzimuth(4,1), PositiveStationTime(4,1), ... PositiveStationName(4,1));
hold on;
polar(NSA,NST,'x');
view([90 270]);
```

You will have to forgive my general poor coding on this matter, this is actually a friend's snippet of code, he asked me for help, I tried for an hour or two, and he gave up but I would like to find the answer.

So the solution that I am looking for is some command that will allow me to plot arrays of strings, specified by arrays of locations defined by my data points, in a polar coordinate system. As it stands, I am not even sure how the text(x,y, 'string') functions in the polar coordinate plane. I think it is built for a euclidean coordinate system as opposed to the polar. I was wondering if there were any shortcuts short of hard-coding the text to appear at the same area of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `polar` function itself does all the hard work of converting the coordinates.  So pull the values directly from the plot:

```
h = polar(PSA,PST,'.'); % easiest way to get handle to plot
x = get(h,'XData');
y = get(h,'YData');
text(x,y, ' \leftarrow foo');  % puts same text next to every point
text(x(3),y(3),' \leftarrow three'); % puts text next to specific point
```

If you have a list (e.g. cell array of strings) of text to put next to individual points, you can use a loop and something like the following:

```
text(x(n),y(n), [' \leftarrow ', stationname{n}]);
```

Comment: So sorry this took so long to confirm but this is absolutely the correct answer.